# Building and running a ASP.Net Core 3.1 in Docker

Tags: angular, docker, asp.net-core

It's safe to say I don't understand docker at all. But given how much hype it has I want to understand it. Thus I am trying to create a docker image of a working web-app built in Dot Net Core 3.1.

The web app is comprised of two parts. A frontend built in angular 9 and a backend built in ASP.Net Core 3.1.

The Angular SPA is compiled and placed inside of the /wwwroot/ folder during build and not built by .net core (because I want to keep them separate).

All this works great on a standard IIS server which this is all deployed to using Azure Devops and CI/CD.

Now. I'm trying to create a docker image of this. So far I have arrived at this `Dockerfile`. Which builds without any errors.

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1-buster-slim AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-buster AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["Backend", "backend"]
RUN dotnet restore "backend/src/HolidayPlanner.Web/HolidayPlanner.Web.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "backend/src/HolidayPlanner.Web"
RUN dotnet build "HolidayPlanner.Web.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

# Angular
FROM node:12.2.0 as angular
WORKDIR /src
ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH
COPY ["Frontend/HolidayPlanner-frontend-v2", "frontend/angular/source"]
#"outputPath": "../../Backend/src/HolidayPlanner.Web/wwwroot/",
RUN npm install -g @angular/cli
WORKDIR /src/frontend/angular/source 
RUN npm install
RUN npm run build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "HolidayPlanner.Web.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
COPY --from=angular /src/frontend/Backend/src/HolidayPlanner.Web/wwwroot wwwroot
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "HolidayPlanner.Web.dll"]
```

This is pieced together using ***alot*** of googling. Feel free to point out any errors. Also note that the reason I copy the Angular buildresult from another folder is because Angular outputs its result to `"outputPath": "../../Backend/src/HolidayPlanner.Web/wwwroot/",` This is because they are separate, and by doing it this way I can use `ng build --watch` in VS-Code while running the backend and get the frontend injected into the asp net core app at runtime. This works great without the docker parts.

So, now to the problem. I cant get the docker image to run more than a second.
I can build the image with `docker build HolidayPlanner -t HolidayPlanner`, this results in something like `Successfully built sb1e10ca071a` being printed.

Then when I try to run it with `docker run -p 5000:5000 --name HolidayPlanner HolidayPlanner` it prints a long line of random numbers and letters and nothing else. If i type `Docker PS` really fast I can see the container is running, but it exits in seconds. The same thing happens if I start it from the Docker UI. In the desktop app I can see `Exited(0)` printed under the image. If I go into it there are no logs or anything useful.

Are there logs? The logs tab on the image in the UI is empty.

How do I figure out what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out why. Apparently you need to set the environment variable in the docker file. Wish I could inject this at a later time, but at least this works.

```
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "HolidayPlanner.Web.dll", "--environment=Development"]
```

Edit: I found a better solution. Instead of setting the environment in the `ENTRYPOINT` it can be sent in at container start.

```
docker run -dit -p 80:80 HolidayPlanner:latest -e environment='Development'
```

Comment: I really don't like this solution